# How would I add a static Main() method to this example?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have recently tried to start learning C# after previously working with PowerShell quite a lot. I have been trying to look at examples of wrapping PowerShell functions within a Visual Studio package.

I was particularly looking at the example from SimonWahlin [here](https://github.com/SimonWahlin/PS2exe/tree/master/Example3). However when I try and build it, it says that the Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point. I knew that a program requires a Main() method and have read some of the documentation from Microsoft, but cannot understand how to introduce the method in to this example.

I appreciate this is not a great question, but hopefully someone can help me. Please let me know if I need to add anything, I am a newbie with this language.

Comment: Since your question is about WPF, you usually don't want to add a static Main method. This begs the question of why would you want/need to do that? Or is it just about placating the error message as such? Perhaps you have just chosen an incorrect project type (i.e., a project type that is not WPF-related)...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was following the guidance on this [site](https://blog.simonw.se/compiling-powershell-to-exe/), and it indicated using a Console App there, but maybe his further examples require a different kind of project type. I'd guess as it's WPF I should have picked C# Desktop App or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from SimonWahlin is a WPF project, which doesn't need a Main method.

However, he has an error in his example. If you look at `App.xaml` it has `<Application x:Class="Example2.App"` at the top, but there is no class with that name. I should instead refer to `Example3.App`.

Try to change that and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I did notice that one, however I've used the same project as he used in his example [here](https://blog.simonw.se/compiling-powershell-to-exe/), which is my fault.